# How to properly catch an error with react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am new with react native and I am trying catching an error in this way

```
Linking.openURL('test').catch(err =>
     alert('error' + err)
   );
```

But If I try to log the error like this

```
Linking.openURL('test').catch(err =>
     alert('error' + err); // error in this line
     console.log(err);
   );
```

I get a syntax error because of the comma.

Answer (score 2):

You're just missing the braces in the arrow function.

```
Linking.openURL('test').catch(err => {
   alert('error' + err); // error in this line
   console.log(err);
});
```

You need braces if your arrow function has more than one sentence.

If you don't have braces, you should only have one sentence whose result will be automatically returned.